# How do you say "Which instrument do you play" in French?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, questions

Since to play an instrument in French is "Jouer de", I wonder where the *de* goes when it's interrogative. I think "Which instrument do you play" in French would be "Quel instrument jouez-vous" but there's no *de*. So, do you say "Quel instrument dont jouez vous" or "Dont instrument jouez vous". I just don't know where the *de* goes.

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure to say "This is the instrument which I play" in french is "C'est l'instrument dont je joue". But is it possible to say "ceci est"?

Comment: "Ceci est" implies you're showing it, with your finger for instance. The question suits more in a casual conversation, where you don't have your instrument with you.

Comment: Given that this is FL&U, you probably don't need to specify *in French* in question titles, Chaplin. We figure you probably aren't here for advice on Mandarin.

Answer (score 8):

The grammatically correct formal sentence would be:

- De quel instrument jouez-vous ?

A still grammatical spoken French:

- De quel instrument est-ce que vous jouez ?

In non formal, real life, you'll more often hear the casual :

- Vous jouez de quel instrument ?

or even:

- Tu joues (de) quoi comme instrument ?

Comment: _De quel instrument est-ce que vous jouez ?_ is another grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: @biozic Yes it is. Suggestion added, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can say "De quel instrument jouez vous ?" or "Quel instrument jouez vous ?" in a more familiar way.

Answer (score 0):

"**De**" goes at begining.

- **De** quel instrument jouez-vous ?
- Je joue **de** la flûte.

EDIT :

You can use the verb "**pratiquer**" without "**de**"

- Quel instrument pratiquez-vous ?
- Je pratique l'accordéon.

Answer (score 0):

Indirect object complement goes first in this case (de quel, duquel, auquel and such)

> De quel instrument jouez-vous/joues-tu ?